# Seeking a good quality reference for "lifting the exponent"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

This is copy/pasted from a submitted coauthored paper of mine:

> **Lemma**: Let $k \ge 1$ and $p$ be prime.  If $a \equiv b \pmod p$, $c \ge 0$ and $c \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k-1}}$, then $a^c \equiv b^c \pmod {p^{k}}$.

A reviewer pointed out that this is called *lifting the exponent* (I had no idea).  Indeed, I found that it's a consequence of the *Second Form of LTE* on the [Art of Problem Solving](http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h324597):

> **Second Form of LTE**: Let $ x,y$ be two integers, $n$ be an odd positive integer, and $p$ be an odd prime such that $ p\mid x + y$ and none of $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $p.$ then: $$v_p( x^n + y^n ) =v_p( x + y ) + v_p( n ).$$

(Here $v_p(m)$ is the largest non-negative integer for which $p^{v_p(m)}$ divides $m$.)

I'd like to add a reference to our paper, but I'm not sure where to look.  Searching for `"lifting the exponent"` in Google Books gives a single conference proceedings book containing the result, but in some completely irrelevant paper.  Similarly, searching for `"lifting the exponent"` in Google Scholar gives places its mentioned which are completely irrelevant our paper.

**Question**: What is a good quality reference for "lifting the exponent"?

I guess I'm looking for a reference in a number theory textbook; something better than a random paper which mentions it.

Comment: I believe this was covered in this text http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Theory-Numbers-Ivan-Niven/dp/0471625469 (not entirely sure though)

Comment: I managed to get a copy; Section 2.6 (Prime Power Moduli) discusses congruences $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k}$ and [Hensel's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel's_lemma).  (This is referred to from "lifting solutions" in the index.)  Unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem to be what I'm after though.

Comment: Generalizations of that lemma make a lot of sense in the context of $p$-adic logarithms. Cf. the version in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4669677/96384

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the OP is still interested in the question after so long time, but the second form of LTE is typically attributed to É. Lucas:

> É. Lucas, *Théorie des Fonctions Numériques Simplement Periodiques*, Amer. J. Math. **1** (1878), 184–196, 197-240, 289–321,

and R. D. Carmichael:

> R. D. Carmichael, *On the Numerical Factors of Certain Arithmetic Forms*, Amer. Math. Monthly **16** (1909), no. 10, 153–159.

In particular, Carmichael fixed a mistake in Lucas' original work in the $2$-adic case.

Comment: Thank you.  [Our paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/15M1024615) [open access] was already published, and we just wrote "Lemma 2 is a case of a folklore result known as “lifting the exponent.”"  But I'll know where to look if it comes up again.