# Similarity of Lifting the Exponent Lemma in Pell numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Pell number is a term of the sequence $\{P_n\}$ determined by a recurrence relation
$$P_{n+2}=2P_{n+1}+P_n, P_0=0, P_1=1.$$

Let $v_p(x)$ be the $p$-adic valuation of an integer $x$ (the number of times $x$ is divisible by $p$). Is the following conjecture correct?

(I) $v_2(P_n)=v_2(n)$,

(II) For any natural number $m$, if a Pell number $P_n$ is divisible by an odd prime $p$,
$$v_p(P_{mn})=v_p(P_n)+v_p(m).$$

---

The reason for making this conjecture is that I learned the following facts about the Fibonacci number $F_n$ determined by
$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n, F_0=0, F_1=1.$$
(I) If $F_n$ is even: $v_2(F_{2n})=v_2(F_n)+1$ if $n$ is even, and $v_2(F_{2n})=v_2(F_n)+2$ if $n$ is odd.

(II) For any natural number $m$, if a Fibonacci number $F_n$ is divisible by an odd prime $p$,
$$v_p(F_{mn})=v_p(F_n)+v_p(m).$$

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the valuation ring of the local field $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{5})$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$.

It is known that (II) can be proved using ''$\mathfrak{p}$-adic log'' of $K$.
$$\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\ \overline{\phi}=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2},$$
$$v_{\mathfrak{p}}(F_n)=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(n)+v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\log(\phi\overline{\phi}^{-1}))-v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\sqrt{5}),$$
$$v_{\mathfrak{p}}(F_{mn})=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(mn)+v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\log(\phi\overline{\phi}^{-1}))- v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\sqrt{5}).$$
Let $e$ be the ramification index of $\mathfrak{p}$. We get (II) because $v_{\mathfrak{p}}=ev_p$.

I don't know enough about ''$\mathfrak{p}$-adic log'', so I don't know if similar proposition for Pell numbers can be done in the same way.

---

Please let me know if there is no problem with the following intuitive transformation of formulas, and if there is a problem, how to fix it?

Pell number $P_n$ is given by
$$\phi=1+\sqrt{2},\ \psi=1-\sqrt{2},$$
$$P_n=\dfrac{\phi^n-\psi^n}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the valuation ring of $K=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ be the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ , can $v_p$ be extended to $v_{\mathfrak{p}}$?
$\sqrt{2}$ is the square root of $2$ of $K$.

$v_{\mathfrak{p}}(P_n)=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\phi^n-\psi^n)-v_{\mathfrak{p}}(2\sqrt{2})$

$=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\phi^n\psi^{-n}-1)-v_{\mathfrak{p}}(2\sqrt{2})$ ($\psi\in\mathcal{O}^{\times}$ correct?)

$=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(\log(\phi^n\psi^{-n}))-v_{\mathfrak{p}} (2\sqrt{2})$

$=v_{\mathfrak{p}} (n\log(\phi\psi^{-1}))- v_{\mathfrak{p}} (2\sqrt{2})$

$=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(n)+v_{\mathfrak{p}}(n\log(\phi\psi^{-1}))-v_{\mathfrak{p}}(2\sqrt{2}) $

Similarly
$$v_{\mathfrak{p}}(P_{mn})=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(mn)+v_{\mathfrak{p}}(n\log(\phi\psi^{-1}))-v_ {\mathfrak{p}}(2\sqrt{2})$$
is correct?

If the above is correct we get
$$ v_{\mathfrak{p}}(P_{mn})=v_{\mathfrak{p}}(P_n)+ v_{\mathfrak{p}}(m).$$

Perhaps the situation changes depending on whether $p=2$ or $p\neq2$, but I don't have the knowledge to understand this.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me advertise the following version of the Lifting The Exponent Lemma. As setup, let $K$ be any characteristic zero field with a nonarchimedean $p$-adic valuation $v_p: K \rightarrow \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ with $v_p(p)=1$ (i.e. the restriction of $v_p$ to $\mathbb Q$ is the standard $p$-adic valuation). Then for any two elements $x,y \in K$, and all $n \in \mathbb N$, the following holds:

> **LTE (Lifting The Exponent) Lemma**
>
> If $v_p (x-y) > v_p(x) + \dfrac{1}{p-1}$ then  $v_p(x^n -y^n) = (n-1)\cdot v_p(x) + v_p(x-y)  +v_p(n)$.
>
> [Special Case $v_p(x) = 0$: If $v_p (x-y) > \dfrac{1}{p-1}$ then  $v_p(x^n -y^n) = v_p(x-y)  +v_p(n)$.]

A **proof** goes like this: Via multiplying through with $y^{-n}$ (note that the condition implies $v_p(x) = v_p(y)$), WLOG we are in the special case with $y=1$ i.e. $x = 1+r$ for some $r \in K$ with $v_p(r) > \dfrac{1}{p-1}$.

Then $x^n-y^n = (1+r)^n – 1 = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} r^k$ and it suffices to consider the two cases

**Case A.** $n=p$, where $v_p (\binom{p}{k} r^k) \begin{cases} =v_p(r) + 1 \qquad \quad \text{ for } k=1 \\ \ge kv_p(r) +1 \qquad \text{ for } 2 \le k \le p-1 \\  = pv_p(r) \qquad \qquad\text{ for }k=p \end{cases}$

By the assumption $v_p(r) > \dfrac{1}{p-1}$ the first one is smaller than all the others, hence $=v_p((1+r)^n – 1)$.

**Case B.** $\gcd(p,n) =1$, where $v_p (\binom{n}{k} r^k) \begin{cases} = v_p(r) \text{ for } k=1 \\ \ge kv_p(r) \text{ for } 2 \le k \le n \end{cases}$

and the assumption ($v_p(r) >0$ would suffice) again guarantees the first one is smaller than all the others, and hence $=v_p((1+r)^n – 1)$. $\square$

---

This  implies both your assertions about the $P_n = \dfrac{\phi^n - \psi^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$, as follows.

First note that $v_p(\phi) = v_p(\psi) = 0$ for all $p$ (e.g. since $\phi, \psi$ are roots of $X^2+2X-1$), so we are in the "Special Case".

In case $p$ odd we have $v_p(2\sqrt{2}) = 0$, hence $v_p(P_n) = v_p(\phi^n-\psi^n)$ for all $n$. Now your assertion (II) is the lemma applied to $x=\phi^n, y=\psi^n$ (and $n=m$, sorry), noting that the hypothesis of that assertion is $v_p(P_n) \ge 1 >\dfrac{1}{p-1}$.

In case $p=2$ we have $v_2(2\sqrt{2}) = \frac32$, hence $0=v_2(P_1) = v_2(\phi-\psi) – v_2(2\sqrt{2})$ i.e. $v_2(\phi-\psi) = \frac32 > \dfrac{1}{2-1}$. So $$v_p(P_n) = v_p(\phi^n - \psi^n) - \frac32 \stackrel{LTE}= \frac32 + v_p(n) -\frac32 = v_p(n)$$ for all $n$.

---

Now, your proposed proof works just as well, and is more conceptual by using the $p$-adic logarithm. In fact, I recommended that line of thought [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3733159/96384). However, you have to be careful about two things (which, furthermore, might interfere with each other):

1. Normalizing the extended valuation $v_{\mathfrak p}$, which is $e\cdot v_p$ for the ramification index of the field: That might cause some case distinctions which ultimately don't matter but make a proof cumbersome.
2. The two facts $$\log(x^n) = n \log(x)$$ and $$v_p(\log(x)) = v_p(x-1)$$ are not as trivial as they are beautiful. In fact, the first one does hold as long as $v_p(x) > 0$, but the second one is **valid in general only if** $v_p(x-1) > \dfrac{1}{p-1}$ (as it should, because otherwise why would that assumption be needed in our version of LTE). Cf. Corollary 8.6 and Theorem 8.7 in [K. Conrad's superb summary of $p$-adic series](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/infseriespadic.pdf). This ultimately relies on the same computations as the straightforward algebra above.

In fact, the number $\dfrac{1}{p-1}$ (which annoyingly is $<1$ for odd $p$ but $=1$ for $p=2$) occurs again and again in this theory, as it is the break point where the two operations "raising to the $p$-th power" and "multiplying with $p$" switch places (as to which one has more effect on the valuation).